# Как правильно делать автообновление приложения?

Tags: java, android, update

Я хочу обновлять моё приложение автоматически. Подскажите, как это сделать. Этот вариант не работает:

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path_to.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
//или если установка из маркета
installIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=app.package.name"));
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Я это хочу делать так: приложение подгружает с сервера apk и как-нибудь обновляется. Я много чего перепробовал, но дельного результат не получил. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html - можно так попробовать

Comment: Что-то откуда-то, кроме как с Google Play устанавливать плохая идея. Только офф. канал является безопасным. Как это правильно делать, описано тут: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates